# How to set up a 'through' model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I am trying to create an app with a 'person' model, and 'event' model and an 'event_person' model to store the details of which people are attending which events.

I have set this up so there are many events for each person, which relate through the event_person model. However, I am getting an error when running the app and I can't understand what I have done wrong.

Person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :team
has_many :events, through: :event_people
validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
scope :ards,  ->{ where("team_id = ?",2)}
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :people
validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Event_person model:

```
class EventPerson < Event
belongs_to :people
belongs_to :events
#accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, :people
validates :role, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
end
```

The error I get is

```
Could not find the association :event_people in model Person
```

when I try and show an entry in the person model, and highlights a line in my people_controller.rb file:

```
 def show
    @people = Person.find(params[:id])
    @events = @people.events
end
```

The line it highlights is `@events = @people.events` as the problem, but as I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `has_many :event_people` on `Person`:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :event_people
  has_many :events, through: :event_people
  ...
end
```

Also, this seems all munged up:

```
class EventPerson < Event
  belongs_to :people
  belongs_to :events
  ...
end
```

I would expect `EventPerson` to inherit from `ApplicationRecord`, not `Event`. And, `people` and `events` to be in their singular form, like?

```
class EventPerson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :event
  ...
end
```

I don't really know what you're trying to do with `people`, here:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :people
  ...
end
```

Perhaps you actually meant:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_people
  has_many :people, through: :event_people
  ...
end
```

Also, it's a little weird to say `@people = Person.find(params[:id])` here:

```
def show
  @people = Person.find(params[:id])
  @events = @people.events
end
```

Because `Person.find(params[:id])` is going to return a single record, not a collection of records. I would expect to see:

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @events = @person.events
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Am a newcomer to all this MVC/ruby on rails stuff, so have been struggling to get to grips with the singularity/plurality of the naming conventions. I have made the changes you suggested and get a new interesting error: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'event_people_events.person_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` INNER JOIN `events` `event_people_events` ON `events`.`id` = `event_people_events`.`event_id` WHERE `event_people_events`.`person_id` = 6`

Comment: It looking for a table called event_people_events, which is wrong, and am guessing is due to a naming issue somewhere. But where?

Comment: I figured it out: `class EventPerson < Event` needed to be `class EventPerson < ApplicationRecord`

Comment: Yeah, I just spotted that, too. And added it to answer. (Sorry, was doing some debugging in the background.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really great answer.